# Cannot disable MultiAZ on RDS instance using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudformation

I have deployed an instance of a RDS PostgreSQL database with MultiAZ enabled, using CloudFormation. When I try to remove MultiAZ I get the following error from CloudFormation:

> CloudFormation cannot update a stack when a custom-named resource requires replacing. Rename  and update the stack again.

The only parameters I changed in the resource template are `MultiAZ` (set from `true` to `false`) and `AvailabilityZone` (set from no value to fixed). The [CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbinstance.html) documentation states that both these parameter do NOT require resource replacement, only "some interruptions". So the following should not apply to my use case:

> DBInstanceIdentifier
>
> [...]
>
> If you specify a name, you can't perform updates that require replacement of this resource. You can perform updates that require no or some interruption. If you must replace the resource, specify a new name.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the `AvailabilityZone` parameter. It looks like updating it requires replacing the resource, contrary to what is written in the documentation. I worked around the issue by removing the parameter from my template.